# How to use JS Module for AlpineJS app to Static HTML

Tags: javascript, html, module, alpine.js

I want to make some alternative to work with js module on static html based on module js stucture that introduced on AlpineJS

```html
<div x-data="drpd">
    <!--2. With JS Modul. NotWorking-->
    <button @click="toggle">Open/Close from Module</button>
    <div x-show="open">Hello, I'm example number 2</div>
</div>
<script type="module" src="./appm.js"></script>
```

**appm.js**

```js
import Alpine from './cdn.min.js'
import dropdown from './d.js'

Alpine.data('drpd', dropdown)

Alpine.start()
```

**d.js**

```js
export default () => ({
    open : false,

    toggle() {
        this.open = ! this.open
    }
})
```

How to make it work as an alternative of the basic implementation AlpineJS by using JavaScript module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, however you need to use the ES module build of Alpine.js not the CDN version (you cannot import from the CDN build). You can create a temporary directory, `cd` into that then:

```
npm install alpinejs
```

to install Alpine.js. After that you can find the module build JS file at the `node_modules/alpinejs/dist/module.esm.js` location. Copy `module.esm.js` to the project directory and modify `appm.js` to import from that file:

```
import Alpine from './module.esm.js'
```

You can also download the module file from [NPM online registry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/alpinejs?activeTab=code) (navigate to the same location as before).

Comment: Yes, I can use it as an alternative, thanks

Comment: but it doesn't seem to be best practice, because I'm having some issues with my other components that use <script src="./cdn.min.js" defer></script> like x-teleport to double output & reusable data from common js scripts not running instead scripts my module is running properly . I'd better stick with a non-module js script for this case. but still my topic here is answered here.

Comment: Nowadays [Vite.js](https://vitejs.dev/) is so easy to use I'm just using it to serve/bundle Alpine.js too. Usually I'm using TailwindCSS as well, so the build step is already required the minimize the CSS file.

Comment: Yes, in this case I want to practicing learn a web based app that can be easily accessible & developed through cross-platform especially on my mobile device which vite.js doesn't support arm-based processor yet to run their modules. (Last time I try it)